# python, dictionary in a data frame, sorting

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a python data frame called wiki, with the wikipedia information for some people. 
Each row is a different person, and the columns are : 'name', 'text' and 'word_count'. The information in 'text' has been put in dictionary form (keys,values), to create the information in the column 'word_count'.

If I want to extract the row related to Barack Obama, then:

```
row = wiki[wiki['name'] == 'Barack Obama']
```

Now, I would like the most popular word. When I do:

```
adf=row[['word_count']]
```

I get another data frame because I see that:

```
type(adf)=<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

and if I do

```
adf.values
```

I get:

```
array([[ {u'operations': 1, u'represent': 1, u'office': 2, ..., u'began': 1}], dtype=object)
```

However, what is very confusing to me is that the size is 1

```
adf.size=1
```

Therefore, I do not know how to actually extract the keys and values. Things like `adf.values[1]` do not work

Ultimately, what I need to do is sort the information in word_count so that the most frequent words appear first.
But I would like to understand how to access a the information that is inside a dictionary, inside a data frame... I am lost about the types here. I am not new to programming, but I am relatively new to python.

Any help would be very very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the name column is unique, then you can change the column to the index of the `DataFrame` object:`wiki.set_index("name", inplace=True)`. Then you can get the value by: `wiki.at['Barack Obama', 'word_count']`.

With your code:

```
row = wiki[wiki['name'] == 'Barack Obama']
adf = row[['word_count']]
```

The first line use a bool array to get the data, here is the document: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

`wiki` is a `DataFrame` object, and `row` is also a `DataFrame` object with only one row, if the name column is unique.

The second line get a list of columns from the `row`, here is the document: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics

You get a `DataFrame` with only one row and one column.

And here is the document of `.at[]`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting

Comment: Thank you very much, that works perfectly! 

I do not understand the logic. 
Why is it possible to extract the information with 
wiki.at['Barack Obama','word_count']
 but it was not possible with 
row[['word_count']] 
as I had previously tried ? If you know something useful I could read to understand this, could you please point me to it? Or maybe if you could detail this that would be really good also. 
Thanks you very much

Comment: @user3177938 I added some document links, please check it.